# Как избавится от ошибки BadHeaderError в Django?

Tags: python, django

У меня есть форма обратной связи с тремя полями: name, email, message.
Данная форма работает, отправляет письма на емайл. Но когда "юзер" заполняет поле message с разрывом строк, то-есть оформляет примерно так:
Hello!(новая строка)My name is Mike.(новая строка) I want to leave a feedback......... Я получаю ошибку BadHeaderError. В файле views.py я сделал исключение:

```
try:
    send_mail(subject, email, message, recipients)
    except BadHeaderError:
        return HttpResponse('Invalid header found')
return HttpResponse('Thank you for your message')
```

но это не решение проблемы.

Python3.5 and Django1.9

Comment: Я чего-то не понял, как оно у вас вообще работает. Если верить документации Django, у вас перепутаны местами второй и третий аргументы. Ну или функция send_mail какая-то совсем сторонняя

Comment: >у вас перепутаны местами второй и третий аргументы
ага, вы правы, только что изменил и всё заработало. Спасибо, сам бы я не догадался